# Prolog - wolf goat cabbage

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof, river-crossing-puzzle

I'm working on a puzzle game named "wolf goat cabbage". The programming language is Prolog.

```
change(e,w).
change(w,e).
move([X,X,Goat,Cabbage],wolf,[Y,Y,Goat,Cabbage]) :- change(X,Y).
move([X,Wolf,X,Cabbage],goat,[Y,Wolf,Y,Cabbage]) :- change(X,Y).
move([X,Wolf,Goat,X],cabbage,[Y,Wolf,Goat,Y]) :- change(X,Y).
move([X,Wolf,Goat,Cabbage],nothing,[Y,Wolf,Goat,Cabbage]) :- change(X,Y).

oneeq(X,X,WW).
oneeq(X,WWW,X).

safe([Man,Wolf,Goat,Cabbage]) :-
        oneeq(Man,Goat,Wolf),
        oneeq(Man,Goat,Cabbage).

wgc([e,e,e,e],[]).

wgc(Config,[FirstMove|OtherMoves]) :-
        move(Config,FirstMove,NextConfig),
        safe(NextConfig),
        wgc(NextConfig,OtherMoves).
```

To make it work, I call  `length(X,7),wgc([w,w,w,w],X).` and it shows the result. The problem is that it shows many times first result and then the second result:

```
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
X = [goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat] ;
false.
```

How to show only one time both results? I tried to add ! symbol to wgc:

```
wgc(Config,[FirstMove|OtherMoves]) :-
        move(Config,FirstMove,NextConfig),
        safe(NextConfig),
        wgc(NextConfig,OtherMoves), !.
```

...but it show only the first result one time.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Probably not very helpful, but can't resist: http://xkcd.com/1134/

Comment: @hyde: thanks, really great site you pointed out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setof` predicate to get a list of unique solutions:

```
setof(X, (length(X,7),wgc([w,w,w,w],X)), Sols).

X = X
Sols = [[goat, nothing, cabbage, goat, wolf, nothing, goat], [goat, nothing, wolf, goat, cabbage, nothing, goat]]
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Answer (score 7):

You are getting here redundant answers/solutions. To eliminate the redundant answers of a (terminating) `Goal` simply wrap that goal with `setof(t, Goal, _).`  Note that the last argument is just `_`, you could also write `[t]` instead.

```
?- length(X,7), setof(t,wgc([w,w,w,w],X),_).
   X = [goat,nothing,cabbage,goat,wolf,nothing,goat]
;  X = [goat,nothing,wolf,goat,cabbage,nothing,goat].
```

This works as long as the answers are ground answers.

Collecting the solutions in a list explicitly as @SergeyDymchenko suggests, requires to give a new variable name to that list and represent all solutions in a single list which might be more costly than leaving this to the implementation. In this concrete case, however, there is no inherent difference.